# Haskell group list until group satisfies a predicate

Tags: list, haskell

How can I group a list such that each group is "closed" as soon as a given predicate no longer holds. Something like

```
groupWhile :: [Int] -> ([Int]->Bool) -> [[Int]]
```

such that

```
groupWhile [1,2,3,5,7,1,3,5,7] (\xs ->  (<=4) $ length $ filter odd xs) 
     = [[1,2,3,5,7],[1,3,5,7]]
```

I need this for a card game, where I want to group events into rounds, such that each round has four cards in it. However not all events are "card" events (the even numbers in the above example).

None of the Data.List and Data.List.Split functions seem to do such things. Predicates always seem to be applied to the source list elements.

Comment: How do you handle even numbers after the fourth odd number (as in 1,2,3,4,7,2,2) and what happens if you reach the last number and the last group has less than 4 cards?

Comment: The predicate should have been (<=4), I corrected this. Even numbers after the fourth odd number would still be appended to the group, because the predicate still holds. If the last round has less than four cards I am happy with a nibbled round, i.e. when the input list is exhausted the last group is closed.

Comment: I think the predicate was correct before: `>>> groupWhile [1,2,3,5,7,1,3,5,7] ((<=4) . length . filter odd)
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],Interrupted`

Comment: I see you based your answer on the original predicate (==). "While (==)" is a bit misleading, so I changed it.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the whole change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple when you reduce it to its basics: scan through sublists of a given list in ascending order by length and return the longest list which satisfies the predicate. Then just recurse on whats left.

```
groupWhile _    [] = []
groupWhile pred xs = let (a,b) = splitAtFunc pred xs in a : groupWhile pred b

splitAtFunc f xs = last $ filter (f . fst) (zip (inits xs) (tails xs))
```

I'm pretty sure that calling `inits` and `tails` will traverse the list twice while but you can easily fuse the two functions:

```
initsAndTails xs = ([], xs) : case xs of
                                []      -> []
                                x : xs' -> map (\(a,b) -> (x:a, b)) $ initsAndTails xs'
```

Comment: There's no need for manual fusion; laziness means they get evaluated exactly  the same way even when they're separated.

Comment: The pleasingly idiomatic `splitAtFunc` is implicitly fused at runtime by the lazy evaluation idiom. Mmmmmmm. That's just _nice_. Well done, Haskell. Great comment, @J.Abrahamson.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I didn't know how to test my hypothesis about `initsAndTails` so I was really just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

At it's most basic, we have

```
   groupWhile as pred = collect [] as where
     collect acc []     = reverse acc
     collect acc (x:xs) =
       let acc'  = x:acc
           racc' = reverse acc'
       in if pred racc'
          then racc' : collect [] xs
          else collect acc' xs
```

though that does a lot of reversing. We can compute it more directly by using two functions from `Data.List`.

```
import Data.List (inits, tails)

-- forall finite (ls :: [a]) . length (inits ls) == length (tails ls)

groupWhile :: [a] -> ([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]]
groupWhile as p = pop (inits as) (tails as) where
  pop [] [] = [] 
  pop (initAs:is) (tailAs:ts)
    | p initAs  = initAs : groupWhile tailAs p
    | otherwise = pop is ts
```

Here `inits` builds the list of possible groups, ordered by inclusion and `tails` builds the "continuation", the remainder of the list provided we pick the current group. They're produced together and whenever we cons a new successfully found group on to our results we continue anew on the "current continuation" `tailAs`. Otherwise, we recur the `pop` function.

Comment: Ha, me either. I'm still trying to pare this code down, but I'll go ahead and eliminate the shadowing.

Comment: Great approach! Still shadowing `init` and `tail` though. ;)

Comment: *Et voila* and more descriptive names ;)

Answer (score 1):

There might be more elegant solutions, but this is a simple way:

```
groupWhile :: [a] -> ([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]]
groupWhile ys p = go [] p ys
    where
        go xs _ []                = [reverse xs]
        go xs p (y:ys) | p (y:xs) = go (y:xs) p ys
        go xs p (y:ys)            = reverse xs : go [y] p ys
```

Note: Because snocing onto the end of a list (`xs ++ [y]`) is really inefficient (`O(n)`) we cons in `go`'s second case (`(y:xs)`) and build up a reverse list this way. Then, when we are done with the current chunk (no more `ys` or `p xs` is false) we reverse the xs again to get them into the right order.

Comment: Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]

Comment: I was missing an `[]` around `reverse xs`, this should work now.

Comment: If you have a predicate such as `\xs -> length xs <= 4` then the last item in the result will only have four elements if there are enough of them. The predicate still holds though for that group though.

Comment: And you get nothing when you don't have at least one complete round. I understand this. However, I would prefer to see the last round even when it is not complete. It would also be more in line with what splitEvery from Data.List.Split does.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use the linear recursion method recommended in [sicp](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node15.html), that is, factor out your state (in this case the "current sublist" and the "current list of sublists" into arguments to a tail-call recursive helper function.

This simple solution requires that p not be sensitive to reversing the list.

```
groupWhile :: [Int] -> ([Int]->Bool) -> [[Int]]
groupWhile = groupWhileHelp [] []
  where groupWhileHelp a [] [] _ = reverse a
        groupWhileHelp a b [] _ = reverse $ reverse b : a
        groupWhileHelp a b (x:xs) p | p $ x : b = groupWhileHelp a (x:b) xs p
        groupWhileHelp a b (x:xs) p = groupWhileHelp (reverse b : a) [x] xs p
```

Another simple, classic approach is to use `foldl` (this one reverses the list every time, removing that restriction on p while increasing computation time).  Either recursion scheme could in principle reverse the list each time or not, of course.

```
groupWhile :: [Int] -> ([Int]->Bool) -> [[Int]]
groupWhile l p = reverse $ foldl (addOne p) [] l where
  addOne _ [] x = [[x]]
  addOne p (xs:xss) x | p $ xs ++ [x] = (xs ++ [x]):xss
                      | otherwise = [x]:xs:xss
```